# System Reserved Partition on wrong drive

Tags: windows-10, system-reserved-partition

I have installed Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 a couple of time on my machine. Now I have Windows 10 on my SSD and my data on HDD.

Windows is functioning fine but I see there's a "System Reserved" partition on my HDD despite my OS is on SSD.

I'm not even sure if this partition is for my final Windows 10 or is a redundant partition of my last OS installation.

Is there any way to figure it out?

Comment: Disconnect the HDD if Windows boots then the partition isn’t required and can be deleted.  Alternative, delete all partitions, and install Windows the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ramhound's suggestion, I found out that it was really a redundant partition. I disconnected my HDD and system booted normally.